# javascript return false not working even when the javascript function is returning false

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button

I have a asp.net button like this

```
 <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="txt" OnClientClick="return abc()" />
```

and javascript function like this

```
function abc() {

    return false;

}
```

the problem is on client click the page is posting to the server even when I am returning false in my javascript function.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Is the function being called?

Comment: yes the function is being called

Comment: Does the code look exactly like it is above? If you have a JS Error in that function, the button will post back.

Comment: What is the rendered HTML source code for that button?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the javascript tag to define the javascript function?

try this, this should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function abc() {
    console.log("inside javascript function abc");
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Note I am trying to print some message in console just to make sure that yeah function is getting called or not.